# `inject` does not add the blank space in accumulator

Tags: ruby, string, immutability

In this code:

```
b = ["here", "are", "things"]
b.inject { |str, v| str+="#{v} " }
# => "hereare things "
```

shouldn't the return value be `"here are things"`? I assume it's passing the first value to the accumulator `str`. Is there a way to return `"here are things "`?

Comment: y, know I could use join - was more curious about behavior here. I've only used inject on adding up integers but was just curious if I could use it the way I wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd assume it's passing in the first value to the accumulator

Correct, because initial value is not defined, first element of your collection becomes the initial value. Fix? Provide the initial value:

```
b = ['here', 'are', 'things']
b.inject('') { |memo, elem| memo + "#{elem} " } # => "here are things "
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the space before the word, like this.  *This does not  have trailing space in the result.*

```
["here", "are", "things"].inject { |str, v| str+=" #{v}" }
#=> "here are things"
```

You could also do something like below and still not have trailing space

```
['here', 'are', 'things'].inject { |m, e| "#{m} #{e}" }
#=> "here are things"
```

Comment: Looking at his question, the trailing space appears to be desirable.

Comment: I see, I was trying to emulate `join` behavior